# Select and count all entries and group them according to the entries

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table and i am supposed to count the entries(5,4,3,2,1) per column name

| ID | ClientID | Responsiveness1 | Responsiveness2 | Reliability1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1024 | 3511 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 1025 | 4571 | 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 1026 | 3827 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 1027 | 7652 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1028 | 7778 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1029 | 7612 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I tried counting it manually (Select Count(Responsiveness1) from table where Responsiveness1 = '5') by column name and by the range (5,4,3,2,1) and got the output. Unfortunately though, I have to count it per column and per range then display it on my table.

Is there an easier and more efficient way to do it to have an output of:

| Rate | Responsiveness1 | Responsiveness2 | Reliability1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Instead of having to count it by column name and then inserting it in the output table?

Answer (score 2):

You can join your table with a table of rates and count entries conditionally

```
with rates(n) as (
  values row(1),row(2),row(3),row(4),row(5)
)
select r.n rate,
   sum(Responsiveness1 = r.n) Responsiveness1,
   sum(Responsiveness2 = r.n) Responsiveness2,
   sum(Reliability1 = r.n) Reliability1
from rates r
left join mytable on Responsiveness1 = r.n or Responsiveness2 = r.n or Reliability1  = r.n 
group by r.n
order by r.n desc
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f6zhOpg1)

Comment: Tried the query but somehow it is showing unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0).. will try figuring this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `full join emulation`  for MySql thru `union all` and then `"pivot"` table. This case is usable for an indefinite set of `rate` values.

```
create table Rates (ID int,ClientID int,Responsiveness1 int,Responsiveness2 int,Reliability1 int);
insert into Rates values(1024, 3511, 5, 4, 3);
insert into Rates values(1025, 4571, 5, 3, 5);
insert into Rates values(1026, 3827, 4, 5, 4);
insert into Rates values(1027, 7652, 1, 1, 1);
insert into Rates values(1028, 7778, 2, 2, 2);
insert into Rates values(1029, 7612, 1, 1, 2);

select n rate
      ,max(case when code="Responsiveness1" then qty else 0 end)Responsiveness1
      ,max(case when code="Responsiveness2" then qty else 0 end)Responsiveness2
      ,max(case when code="Reliability1" then qty else 0 end)Reliability1
from ( 
  select "Responsiveness1" code,Responsiveness1 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Responsiveness1
  union all
  select "Responsiveness2" code,Responsiveness2 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Responsiveness2
  union all
  select "Reliability1" code,Reliability1 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Reliability1
  )u
group by n
order by n desc
```

| rate | Responsiveness1 | Responsiveness2 | Reliability1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

I'll add Pivot result example

```
select code
      ,max(case when n=1 then qty else 0 end) rate1
      ,max(case when n=2 then qty else 0 end) rate2
      ,max(case when n=3 then qty else 0 end) rate3
      ,max(case when n=4 then qty else 0 end) rate4
      ,max(case when n=5 then qty else 0 end) rate5
from ( 
  select "Responsiveness1" as code,Responsiveness1 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Responsiveness1
  union all
  select "Responsiveness2" as code,Responsiveness2 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Responsiveness2
  union all
  select "Reliability1" as code,Reliability1 n,count(*) qty
      from Rates r group by Reliability1
  )u
group by code
```

Table

| code | rate1 | rate2 | rate3 | rate4 | rate5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Responsiveness1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Responsiveness2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Reliability1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

What case is suitable in a specific case - customer request or developer preferences:)

Comment: Thanks, now this works.. one more, if I may, what if I pivot it and the rates (5,4,3,2,1) be the table headers and the Responsiveness1, Responsiveness2, etc be the row names? What approach should I use?

Comment: Thank you for this.. trying to modify it to include an inner join to another table relative to the clientID. A little tweaking and i hope i could get it. thanks